# Jhipster app accessible only on localhost and not by host/machine name

Tags: jhipster

I am running an app built using jhipster 6.8.0. The app is accessible on localhost but when I access it using machine name on the network it is not accessible.

I have another app running using spring boot and I can acesss this on both localhost and corp domain using machine name.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior with app built using Jhipster ?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Environment: Windows 10.
2. Create an monolithic application using Jhipster 6.8.0

```
application {
  config {
    baseName TestApp,
    applicationType monolith,
    packageName com.test.app,
    searchEngine elasticsearch,
    prodDatabaseType mysql,
    buildTool maven,
    clientFramework angular,
    useSass true,
    testFrameworks [protractor],
    enableTranslation false,
  }
  entities *
}
```

3. Run the application using the maven wrapper with the default config of server port of 8080.

```
.mvnw
```

4. Access the application on localhost at http://localhost:8080 and the home page loads.
5. Access the application using machine name at http://machinename.domain:8080 and no response.
6. Create an Spring Boot application with webstarter

```
https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.3.1.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web
```

and set the server port as 8080 and access the application on http://localhost:8080 and http://machinename.domain:8080 and both resolve successfully.

Investigated:

- Firewall is excluded since Spring Boot app is accessible on machine name and Jhipster app isn't.
- Switched from undertow to tomcat on Jhipster and still not accessible on machine name host.

Let me know if you need more information than what is provided.

Comment: Have you checked with netstat that your app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080 ?

Comment: Update: Found that one of the Antivirus polices was applied and was blocking the source IP communication on the machine. It did look like it was not Antivirus since the spring boot app was working without any issues when ran through Eclipse.

Comment: What about my question above? Also, what is your point with Eclipse? I thought you were starting the 2 apps the same way with maven.

Comment: netstat did show that app is listening on 0.0.0.0:8080. Regarding Eclipse the application running through Eclipse was running embedded runtime and firewall was not blocking the version of Java. Maven was using the JDK set based on the JAVA_HOME and this process and version was being blocked by antivirus.